How to patch a library in a docker image which I have not compiled from source
I have a Docker image which has been built from a Dockerfile starting with: FROM ubuntu:24.04. This contains a library libaom, whose version can be determined using:
# ls -l /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ | grep aom
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        15 Jun  5 13:21 libaom.so.3 -> libaom.so.3.8.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3948272 Jun  5 13:21 libaom.so.3.8.2

It has been included as a result of these lines in the Dockerfile:
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN apt-get install -y libavif-bin 

As a result of a bug report that I made, I'm told that the library has now been updated to v3.8.3. The question is: how do I get hold of the latest library and ensure that it goes into my Docker image when it gets rebuilt?
I'm not sure whether I need to do some patching or add some special set of apt commands. I can probably figure out how to rebuild the library from source, but I wouldn't know how then to put this into my executable without breaking the package manager.
Any help appreciated - even an explanation of how to figure out what versions are in the base image would be helpful!
